# python function dictionary with variable number of parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, function-pointers

I am trying to create a dictionary which maps strings to functions. The problem is, the functions can have different parameter lengths. Is there a way to handle this.

For ex:

```
myFuncDict
{
'A' : a    ----> def a(param1, param2)
'B  : b    ----> def b(param1)
'C' : c    ----> def c(param1, param2, param3)
}

I want to call functions like:
def test(k):
 myFuncDict[k](params)
```

How can i achieve this? 
kwargs or args is one way to go, but not sure how to handle the above using those without sending extra parameters.

Comment: Why are you doing this? If they have a different API, why are you grouping them? You can make it work but you probably **don't want to**.

Comment: I think there are valid use-cases for something like this @Reut. Actually, I think putting functions in dictionaries is somewhat of a common idiom now. People often use it in-place of a switch statement. I also don't think it should be required that all functions put in the dictionary should have the same signature. That's just to restrictive.

Comment: I think the use case is when they're used in the same context. That means that locally all arguments are available to them. Instead of obfuscating with unpacking you may want some functions to ignore some arguments, for the reward of a consistent API.

Answer (score 3):

Python actually makes this quite simple. You can simply unpack your container of arguments into the function call using the unpacking operator `*`. Here is an example:

```
def a(x):
    print(x)

def b(x, y):
    print x, y

dic = {'a': a, 'b': b}


def call_func(func, params):
    dic[func](*params) # *params is the magic.

call_func('a', (1))
call_func('b', (1, 2))
```

Comment: Just a thought, what if the api was `def a(x, _)` and `def b(x, y)` (obviously meaning `a` ignores `y`). Wouldn't that be so much nicer? :)

Comment: My suggestion isn't specific, it is general. Design your API to be consistent. The use case for these things 99% of the times is to apply some function to the same conceptual set of values (object), only ignoring some of its properties every now and then. Sometimes giving someone an answer how to do something complex is only digging him a deeper hole.

Comment: This is usually the case (the parameters are the same, the subsets are different). And given this is the case, this is a bad idea. Just make the functions with the proper signature (no `*args` and `**kwargs` or the likes) and ignore whatever you don't use. Much cleaner in my opinion. So in this case: `a(param1, param2, _)`, `b(param1, _, _)` and `c(param1, param2, param3)`.

Comment: As @ChristianDean mentioned I would like to call each function in the dict with correct amount of args. Using **kwargs , we would be  passing all parameters without using all of them.

Comment: Ah, okay! Thanks for the clarification @user3696282. Glad you cleared things up. For a second there, I thought we were about to have a twenty comment long debate on your intent & the pros and cons of consist APIs :P